# In a triangle, the semiperimeter $\le$ sum of the medians $\le$ the perimeter

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles

Let $EFG$ be a triangle such that $P$, $N$ and $M$ are the midpoints of $EF$, $EG$ and $FG$ respectively. The problem is to show that:

$$Q/2< EM+FN+GP<Q,$$ where $Q$ is the perimeter of the triangle $EFG$.

My approach: I figured that I'd try using the triangle inequality in the triangles formed inside, but that didn't lead me to anything.

So any hint or help are much appreciated.

Comment: Hi. You used the same letter P both for a point and for a perimeter. Could you please consider using different letters?

Comment: Oops, my bad, sorry for the oversight

Comment: @Billy: no worries, I already corrected in your question.

Comment: The 3 medians divides the triangle into 6 smaller triangles. Apply the triangle inequality to each triangle and you will get the result of the first half.

Comment: For the second part, extend EM till E' such that EM = ME'. See if you can find a parallelogram, and then use the triangle inequality for its diagonal and two sides.

Comment: See  Posamentier, Alfred S., and Salkind, Charles T., Challenging Problems in Geometry, Dover, 1996: pp. 86–87

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properly **D S** suggests:
\begin{align*}
2EM<EG+EF,\\ 2GP<EG+GF,\\ 2FN<EF+FG. 
\end{align*}
By addition,
$2(EM+FN+GP)<2(EF+FG+EG)\ \Rightarrow\ EM+FN+GP<Q$.

Let $O$ be the centroid of $\triangle EFG$.
The left inequality can be obtained like this:
\begin{align*}
OE+OF>EF\Rightarrow\ 2EM/3+2FN/3>EF,\\
OE+OG>EG\Rightarrow\ 2EM/3+2GP/3>EG,\\
OF+OG>EG\Rightarrow\ 2FN/3+2GP/3>FG.\\
\end{align*}
By addition,
$$
4(EM+FN+GP)/3>EF+FG+EG\ \Rightarrow\ EM+FN+GP>3Q/4>Q/2.
$$
This last inequality is in the [book](https://www.isinj.com/mt-usamo/Challenging%20Problems%20In%20Geometry%20Alfred%20Posamentier.pdf) on page 86.
However, the first inequality is not there.

This last inequality can also be proved like this:
\begin{align*}
OE+ON>EN\Rightarrow\ 2EM/3+FN/3>EG/2,\\
OF+OP>FP\Rightarrow\ 2FN/3+GP/3>EF/2,\\
OG+OM>GM\Rightarrow\ 2GP/3+EM/3>FG/2.\\
\end{align*}
By addition,
$$
EM+FN+GP>(EF+FG+EG)/2\ \Rightarrow\ EM+FN+GP>Q/2.
$$

Comment: I didn't understand quite well, can you please re-explain?

Comment: @Billy, thank you for your question. I have updated my answer with new details. If you still have any questions I would be more than happy to answer them.

Comment: Nope, I have no questions left, very clear explanation, thank you so much